# Compiler Issue with auto? Error: in a declarator-list 'auto' must always deduce to the same type

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, auto

```
std::vector<int> vec;
auto i = vec.begin(), j = std::next(i);
```

> Error: in a declarator-list 'auto' must always deduce to the same type

Comment: What compiler are you using? It looks OK to me.

Comment: I"m guessing it's the code.  The person who wrote the compiler is smarter than we are.  Doubt yourself first, last, and always.

Comment: This compiles cleanly in Visual Studio 2012, FWIW.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the (old) compiler

Comment: @duffymo: That becomes markedly less true with new language features.

Comment: Nope, makes as much sense as feeding JDK 6 Java into a version 1.4 compiler.  That wasn't part of the problem statement.  I gave the OP too much credit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compiles fine in g++ on Linux, so it appears to be a compiler bug. [Probably this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/545958#details).

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a compiler error.
See this link below.
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728741
May already have been fixed judging by the comments in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this was an issue on the VS2010 compiler toolchain. Swapped it to 2013 and it was fine.